# How do i create a new account in Draw Something Free?

Tags: draw-something

I really want to play Draw Something, but i need an account. There is no such button as "create account" or anything like that in the home-screen  when i enter the app.

Answer (score 1):

You just log in with Google Play. It should automatically log you in if you have Google Play Games account. You can find out how and why it works here:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2954594?hl=en

If you already have the account, try reinstalling and accept the screen to login with Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

Put your email in but not username press log in it will say password tap on the little forgot my password and it will send an email to you with your password in blue letters hope this helped